# Module Federation with NX Unsatisfied Version React Icons

Tags: reactjs, webpack-module-federation

I'm having an issue with Module Federation in my project.

I have the following `module-federation.config.js` in my `shell` app:

```
/**
 * @type {import('@nrwl/devkit').ModuleFederationConfig}
 **/
const moduleFederationConfig = {
  name: 'shell',
  remotes: ['app-1', 'app-2'],
  shared: (name, config) => {
    // We want react-icons to be tree shaken, and bundled into each host/remote separately.
    if (name === 'react-icons') {
      return false;
    }
    return undefined;
  },
};

module.exports = moduleFederationConfig;
```

Now `app-1` uses `react-icons` and `app-2` does not. If I run `app-2` standalone it works with no problems and if I run my `shell` app and render `app-1` inside that it also works fine.

However, when I try to run `app-1` standalone, it throws the following error:

> Unsatisfied version 0 from monolith-deployment of shared singleton module react-icons (required ^4.4.0)

I'm sure I'm missing something basic, but I'm just to new at module-federation to figure it out.

Here's a warning I get, but I'm not sure what to do with it:

> WARNING in shared module react-icons -> /workspaces/my-repo/node_modules/react-icons/lib/esm/index.js
> No version specified and unable to automatically determine one. No version in description file (usually package.json). Add version to description file /workspaces/my-repo/node_modules/react-icons/lib/package.json, or manually specify version in shared config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the version of `nx` used at the time this was posted had a bug in it that lasted from `v15.8.6` all the way through to `v15.9.2`.

`v15.9.3` fixes it.

**Solution**

Update `nx` to the latest version, or at least avoid using versions `15.8.6`-`15.9.2`